# In Angular 2, ngIF is not working when i am trying with two way binding

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am working with `Angular2` with two way binding concept `[(ngModel)]`.I have form with my page and I have to validate the pristine state of the element. So for validation I have used `ngIf` to check the pristine state of the element. But the condition is not working. I need to check the pristine state for every model change. Below is my `app.component.html` page:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="angular2form(myAngular2Form.employeeDob)" [ngFormModel]="myAngular2Form">

 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employee" name="employee" [(ngModel)]="employeeDob" required  />            
  <div *ngIf="employeeDob.pristine">
    <p>Please enter the date</p>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>

</form>
```

This is my component:

```
 export class AppComponent {

employeeDob: String;

  constructor(private myform: FormBuilder) {
    this.employeeDob = '';
 }
 angular2form(date) {
     alert("date submitted successfully");
 }
 }
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pristine` is a property of the `Control` not of the `value`.

You might want to use

```
<input #employeeDobCtrl="ngForm" type="text" class="form-control" id="employee" name="employee" [(ngModel)]="employeeDob" required  />        
<div *ngIf="employeeDobCtrl.pristine">
```

(for the old forms module)

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="employee" name="employee" [(ngModel)]="employeeDob" #date="ngModel" required  />

  <div [hidden]="date.valid || date.pristine">
    <p>Please enter the date</p>
 </div>`

straight outta documentation

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("" class="form-control" id="employeeDob" [(ngModel)]="employeeDob" name="employeeDob"  [ERROR ->]#employeeDob="ngModel" required  />

Comment: What version of angular are you using? I think that is fixed in newer version. 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9363

Comment: I am using angular - common/core  2.0.0-rc.1"

Comment: Sadly I believe my answer works only for rc.3 and later versions

Answer (score 1):

pristine is true if the user has **not interacted** with the form yet. You probably want to check for **dirty** instead? You can also use the `hidden` tag and replace

```
<div *ngIf="employeeDob.pristine">
```

with:

```
<div [hidden]="employeeDob.pristine">
```